# Event listeners on hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm updating my hibernate from version 3 to 5 and I have in my application context I had the following bean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
            p:mappingResources="standard.hbm.xml">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
         <property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="merge">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

The problem is in hibernate 5 I don't have EventListners and also I don't have IdTransferringMergeEventListener. Do I need this? How can I replace?

Answer (score 0):

from api [IdTransferringMergeEventListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/IdTransferringMergeEventListener.html)

> Extension of Hibernate's DefaultMergeEventListener, transferring the
> ids of newly saved objects to the corresponding original objects (that
> are part of the detached object graph passed into the merge method).

So if you don't use this in your project you can skip it. If you need it , you can just copy listener and register one. I think DefaultMergeEventListener has method `onMerge(MergeEvent event, Map copiedAlready)` that support old IdTransferringMergeEventListener

from [IdTransferringMergeEventListener extends org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener, which has been moved to org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9634) it should be ok.

> We intentionally kept Spring's Hibernate 4 support rather minimal, in
> order to stay close to the native Hibernate 4 ways of doing things. As
> a consequence, we have no plans to reintroduce
> IdTransferringMergeEventListener or any of our former LOB user types,
> all of which were special-purpose classes to work around issues that
> Hibernate should really solve itself - since they have nothing to do
> with Spring and caused repeated maintenance headaches on Spring's
> side.
>
> **You're free to create your own version based on Spring's old
> IdTransferringMergeEventListener**, of course. However, note that the
> way that event listeners can be registered has changed in Hibernate 4:
> This is not possible on a per-SessionFactory level anymore, hence
> Spring cannot support in its LocalSessionFactoryBean either. Check the
> corresponding Hibernate documentation and the corresponding reports on
> the Hibernate JIRA for details.

Comment: This event listener is used for what? Maybe I'm using but I don't know

Comment: it copies the identifiers of objects created with the hibernt merge() method back into original objects.For example when a object is saved for the first time using merge(object) and atfer it you call getId() result is null , with listener id is merged  into saved object and you get real id.

Comment: So yes I'm using... Could you gide me how to implement the behaviour?

Comment: Thanks I will try